# How can I force nitter.net in light theme mode in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, ublock-origin

By default nitter.net appears in a dark theme.
Appending `?theme=Twitter` to a URL makes every page appear in the light theme.

Example:

- https://nitter.net/elonmusk
- https://nitter.net/elonmusk?theme=Twitter

Is there any sort of extension or rule within uBlock origin, which could rewrite every nitter.net URL to add `?theme=Twitter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there any sort of extension or rule within uBlockOrigin, which could rewrite every nitter.net URL?

It's not possible within uBlockOrigin, however read on:

> I was wondering if it's possible to use the "My rules" section to automatically redirect from a specific website's URL to another, while keeping the rest of the link intact.

...

> Not possible. Use for example this instead: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/requestcontrol/

Source: [Add custom redirect rule? : uBlockOrigin](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/jgulbc/add_custom_redirect_rule/)

> **Request Control by tumpio**
>
> An extension for controlling requests.
>
> Provides front-end for Firefox webRequest.onBeforeRequest API for
> request management.
>
> Requests can be controlled with following rules:
>
> - Filter
>
>   Skip URL redirection and remove URL query parameters.
> - Redirect
>
>   **Rewrite requests with support for Pattern Capturing to redirect
>   based on original request URL.** <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>
> - Secure
>
>   Upgrade non-secure HTTP request to secure HTTPS.
> - Block
>
>   Block requests before they are made.
> - Whitelist
>
>   Whitelist request without taking actions of any other rules.

Source: [Request Control – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/requestcontrol/)

Start at [Redirect using pattern capturing](https://github.com/tumpio/requestcontrol/blob/master/_locales/en/manual.wiki#Redirect_using_pattern_capturing) for instructions on how write Redirect Rules.